# 嵐 vs雷雨 is there any difference?

Tags: meaning, kanji

They both mean rain with a thunder?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is a little difference between them.

嵐 means *storm, tempest* (without rain)

雷雨　means *thunderstorm* (雷 + 雨　＝　thunder + rain)

Little note:

嵐（あらし）is also Japanese boy band.

References:

https://jisho.org/search/%20%E5%B5%90
https://jisho.org/search/%20%E9%9B%B7%E9%9B%A8